# How to prompt user to select multiple sheet to copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that takes multiple worksheets and copies data onto a "Combined" sheet.  How can I insert a prompt so that the user can select which sheets to copy?  Here is my current code:

```
Sub Combine()

Dim J As Integer

On Error Resume Next

     Sheets(1).Select
     Worksheets.Add ' add a sheet in first place
     Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
     Sheets(3).Activate
     Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Select
     Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")

     For J = 3 To Sheets.Count - 3 ' from sheet 2 to fourth from last sheet
          Sheets(J).Activate ' make the sheet active
          Range("A3").Select
          Selection.CurrentRegion.Select ' select all cells in this sheets
          Selection.Offset(2, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 2).Select
          Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
     Next

     Sheets(1).Select
     Cells.Select
     Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

I want the user to select the sheets rather than selecting all the sheets.

Comment: Several ways to do this. You could run a loop and prompt for a sheet name with `InputBox`, and validate the input before you continue. Or you could bring prompt the user to pick a `Range` on any sheet with `Application.InputBox` (with the `Type` argument set to require a `Range` - see documentation), and use the `Parent` property of that `Range` object to get the `Worksheet` they picked. Or you could pop a `UserForm` dialog that lists all sheets in a `ListBox`, and have the user check/select the sheets they want to copy from. Have you tried anything to actually prompt the user for a sheet?

Comment: I like the ListBox idea mentioned by @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how to do this with a list box use the following steps:

I. Create a user form

II. Add a list box and set the following properties

```
Liststyle =fmliststyleoption,
multiselect=fmmultiselectmulti
```

III. Add an initialize event and use code similar below to fill

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim name As String

For x = 2 To Sheets.Count
   name = Sheets(x).name
   ListBoxSheets.AddItem name
Next
```

End Sub

[image: Checked list box to select sheets]